# Selenium IDEからIEを指定するとJavaScriptError

Tags: selenium

環境は Windows 8 (64bit), IE11, Selenium IDE 2.8 です。

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver の "Required Configuration" に従って、レジストリの更新と保護モードを全てのゾーンでONに。
IEドライバーを指定してサーバーを起動

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-*.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=.\IEDriverServer.exe
```

Selenium IDEの設定で PlayBackを有効に、ブラウザをIEに設定。

この手順で、手元のVMに入ったwindows8でIEのテストが行えたのですが、(Windows 8, IE11,  Selenium IDE 2.8) の実機で同様にインストール、レジストリの設定、インターネットオプションの設定を行ったところ、どのページでも（yahoo->ヤフオクなどでも）openした次のページへ遷移時にJavaScriptエラーが発生し、全くテストが出来ません。

**メッセージ**

```
[error] JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 78 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:02:37' System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version: '1.8.0_31' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:17658/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
```

Comment: "違う実機"の環境も追記しては如何でしょうか？全く同じという場合、"何が同じ"である事を確認済みなのかを書くと良いと思います。(OS、IE、Javaのバージョンetc.)

Comment: 実機は64bitの様ですが、VMも64bitのWindows 8.1ですか？

Comment: はい、64bitのWindows 8.1です